# Set Audacious to open maximized?

Tags: gnome, mutter, audacious

I'm using Audacious 3.2.1, on Gnome-Shell. However, everytime I open it, it starts not-maximized. Is there a way, like editing the command for the launcher in the Menu Editor, to make Audacious fire up maximized?

I'm not interested on the "maximus" utility.

Any ideas?